Some errata in Petersen's Riemannian Geometry book 3rd?
I am reading Petersen's "Riemannian Geometry" 3rd Edition.
In section 6.1.4 he introduced Jacobi fields along geodesic: if $c$ is a geodesic starting from $p$, given any vector $\dot{J}(0)\in T_pM$, one can construct a Jacobi field via the variation $\bar{c}(s,t)=\mathrm{exp}_p(t(\dot{c}(0)+s\dot{J}(0))), J(t)=\frac{\partial\bar{c}}{\partial s}(0,t)$.
Then he shows that (on page 239) if $c$ is unit speed, then for the distance function $r(x)=|xp|$, $$g(\nabla_{J(t)}\nabla r,J(t))=g(\dot{J}(t), J(t)). (*)$$
It seems that the equation (*) is wrong.
At least it should not be true for all possible $J(t)$, because that would imply $\mathrm{Hess}\ r$ being positive definite in a nonpositive sectional curvature space, as he writes in section 6.2.2 (Page 243):
$$\mathrm{Hess}\ r(J(b),J(b))=g(\nabla_{J(b)} \nabla r, J(b))=g(\dot{J}(b),J(b))=\int_0^b (|\dot{J}(t)|^2+g(\ddot{J}(t),J(t)))\mathrm{d} t>0$$
(Note that for any function $f$ we have $\mathrm{Hess} f(X,Y)=g(\nabla_X\nabla f,Y)$)
However in the Euclidean space (which has $0$ curvature) the Hessian has rank $n-1$ and can't be positive definite. In fact, if we choose the Jacobi field $J(t)=t\dot{c}(0) \in T_{c(t)} \mathbb{R}^n$ along the geodesic $c(t)=t\dot{c}(0)\in \mathbb{R}^n$, the LHS in (*) is zero while the RHS is not.
Am I thinking this correctly? or have I misinterpreted the author? (I have found the errata for 2nd Edition of this book but not 3rd online and this isn't mentioned in the errata)
possible fix (I think I have a complicated fix for this): We know that Jacobi field keeps orthogonal to geodesic if orthogonal at the beginning, that is $J(0)=0,g(\dot{J}(0),\dot{c}(0))=0 \Rightarrow g(J(t),\dot{c}(t))=0$. The author later used (*) to prove $\mathrm{Hess}\ (\frac{r^2}{2}) \ge g$ in nonpositive curvature spaces and he replaces $g_r(J,J)$ with $g(J,J)$ in the proof ($g_r$ means $g=\mathrm{d}r^2+g_r$).
Intuitively, the fact is that the equation (*) above actually holds for only orthogonal Jacobi fields.
Claim. $\nabla_{J(t_0)} \nabla r=\dot{J}(t_0)$ for Jacobi field $J(0)=0,g(\dot{J}(0),\dot{c}(0))=0$ along a unit speed geodesic $c$. (Thus (*) holds for this kind of Jacobi fields)
Proof. We know the Jacobi field $J$ is constructed from the variation $\bar{c}(s,t)=\mathrm{exp}_p(t(\dot{c}(0)+s\dot{J}(0)))$. Let $w(s)=\bar{c}(s,t_0)$, $X$ be a vector field that $X_{w(s)}=\frac{\partial \bar{c}}{\partial t}(s,t_0)$, $f$ be a function: $f(w(s))=|X_{w(s)}|^{-1}$. As $t\rightarrow \bar{c}(s,t)$ is a geodesic (but maybe not unit speed) for every $s$, we have ${\nabla r}|_{w(s)}=fX$. Thus
$$\nabla_{J(t)} \nabla r=\nabla_{\dot{w}(0)}(fX)=f(w(0))\nabla_{\dot{w}(0)} X+\dot{w}(0)(f)\cdot X$$
We know $\nabla_{\dot{w}(0)}X=\frac{\partial^2 \bar{c}}{\partial s \partial t}(0,t_0)=\dot{J}(t_0)$ by the proposition of derivative of vector field along curve in section 6.1.1. That is very close to the answer. Now we compute $f$:
$$|X_{w(s)}|=|\frac{\partial \bar{c}}{\partial t}(s,t_0)|=|\frac{\partial \bar{c}}{\partial t}(s,0)|=|\dot{c}(0)+s\dot{J}(0)|=\sqrt{\dot{c}(0)^2+s^2 \dot{J}(0)^2}$$
Thus $f(w(0))=|\dot{c}(0)^{-1}|=1$ and $\dot{w}(0)(f)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} s} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\dot{c}(0)^2+s^2 \dot{J}(0)^2}}|_{s=0}=0. \blacksquare$

When you write $\mathrm{Hess}\ r(J(t),J(t))=g(\nabla_{J(t)}\nabla r,J(t))=g(\dot{J}(t), J(t))$ (maybe quoting the book) , & then claim "this statement is wrong" , it is not immediately clear whether you are claiming $\mathrm{Hess}\ r(J(t),J(t)) \not =g(\nabla_{J(t)}\nabla r,J(t))=g(\dot{J}(t), J(t))$ or $\mathrm{Hess}\ r(J(t),J(t))=g(\nabla_{J(t)}\nabla r,J(t)) \not =g(\dot{J}(t), J(t))$ or even $\mathrm{Hess}\ r(J(t),J(t)) \not =g(\nabla_{J(t)}\nabla r,J(t)) \not =g(\dot{J}(t), J(t))$ : You might clarify your claim there itself after $(*)$ , maybe while marking it $(**)$ , avoiding confusion.

Thanks! I’ve shorten the equation (*) keeping the second “=“. Actually the first “=“ always holds because of the property of Hessian.

We could make out what you intended , though not immediately. Nice one with the Edit. In Case you had wanted to leave that quote $(*)$ untouched , then you may have made a new line with $(**)$ , though eliminating that middle term is okay too.

Note that the hessian of $r$ is never positive definite, it can only be positive definite on ${\nabla r}^{\perp}$. Indeed, $(\nabla^2 r)(\nabla r, \cdot) = 0$ due to the equation of geodesics $\nabla_{\nabla r} (\nabla_r) = 0$.

@Didier Your nice answer tells exactly my idea in the question :) Now I can confirm that the author forgot to tell they are normal Jacobi fields when writing those equations (However I think the proof for normal Jacobi fields still can't be as simple as the original one in the book)

The Hessian of the distance function $r$ can never be completely positive definite.
Indeed, since $|\nabla r|^2 = 1$ is constant, differentiating in the direction of $\nabla r$ yields
$$
\mathrm{Hess}\,r\,(\nabla r, \nabla r) =  \langle \nabla_{\nabla r} \nabla r, \nabla r\rangle = \frac{1}{2}\nabla r \,|\nabla r|^2 = 0.
$$
However, in a nonpositively curved manifold, it will be positive definite on $\{\nabla r\}^{\perp}$.
The equation
$$
\mathrm{Hess}\, r\, (J(b),J(b)) = \int_0^b(|J'(t)|^2 + \langle J''(t),J(t)\rangle) \mathrm{d}t
$$
is of course not true if you plug in $J(t) = t\,\nabla r$, which is a Jacobi field.
It is only true for normal Jacobi fields, which are Jacobi fields orthogonal to $\nabla r$.
For those normal Jacobi fields, however, this shows the positive definite character of $\mathrm{Hess}\, r$.
As a final remark, let me mention that the fact that $\mathrm{Hess}\, r$ is positive definite on $\{\nabla r\}^{\perp}$ geometrically means that geodesic spheres are (strictly) convex.
(To be completely rigorous, everything here is true for $r$ small enough, away from the cut locus or from conjugate points along the considered geodesic, etc.)
